# Transferring flow ownership in trifacta dataprep

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do you transfer 'ownership' rights of a flow to another account in the Dataprep by Trifacta module of the Google Cloud Platform?
[image]

So far I have found [how to add](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Share-a-Flow_118228660) 'collaborators', but these are not 'owners'. Furthermore it is stated here that a flow, including its input datasets, [can be copied](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Share-Flow-Dialog_118228911) (essentially sending the copy to make the receiver the 'owner'). However, the receiving parties flow does not include the destinations for each recipe. You could add these manually later on, but with a large flow this is quite a hassle.

The background is that an employee (who is owner of the flow) is leaving the firm, hence we want to shutdown the Google account. But before that we need to transfer the flow ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, is not possible to transfer an ownership of Dataprep, is only possible to [share a flow](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Sharing_118228675#sharing-flows). The workaround for you would be to [export the flows](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Export-Flow_118228661) and set up everything.